# How to rewrite URL in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, url-rewriting, cakephp-2.3

I am using Cake 2.3 and I have a URL like this:

```
http://www.example.com/events/event_name
```

I want to show

```
http://www.example.com/event_name
```

I have gone through many links but with no success I am posting here.
Please help me in this.

Comment: *gone through many links* ? show us what you have tried .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in cakephp [official documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html) you can use Router class in your bootstrap.php file like

```
Router::redirect('/posts/*', 'http://google.com', array('status' => 302));
```